# AngularJS: ng-bind-html is delayed about 1 - 1.5 seconds after scope is updated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ng-bind-html

In my directive I have a `$scope.show = ''`. When a user drops an image over a DOM element it updates to `$scope.show = <img src="..." />`.

In my template I have `<span ng-bind-html-unsafe="show"></span>`.

I can see that the $scope is updated right away because I am logging it to the console. However it takes about 1 - 1.5 seconds for it to be binded to the template.

Thanks in advance

Comment: and the question is ?

Comment: "When a user drops and image over a DOM element"... doesn't sound like Angular.Js behavior, sounds like you are manipulating the DOM outside Angular.  How are you alerting Angular to this change?

Comment: Could you please paste your directive.